# How to use relative paths with node-loader and native addon

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron

I have a native addon I am using that works great on my dev machine but fails on any other machine due to the webpack build using an absolute path to the native module instead of a relative one. Here is the error I get:

`/main.prod.js:7543: Uncaught Error: Cannot open /Users/.../app/lib/main.node: Error: dlopen(/Users/.../app/lib/main.node, 1): image not found`

In my main.dev.js I import the file like this: `import main from './lib/main.node';`
In webpack config I have added a module test for .node:

```
export default {
  externals: Object.keys(externals || {}),

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.node$/,
      use: 'node-loader'
    }]
  },
...
```

How can I make sure that my main.node file gets packaged for the build and imported via relative path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by switching to a modified version of node-addon-loader. https://github.com/smt116/node-native-ext-loader